# F-SW22 vs F-SW33 flux. What to these figures mean?

Tags: soldering, flux

I was thinking of purchasing a [no-clean flux pen](http://www.rapidonline.com/Tools-Equipment/Stannol-No-Clean-Flux-Pens-520395) from my supplier, but there are two options, F-SW22 and F-SW33. What do these codes mean and what types of job is each suitable for?

Comment: Could you link to both types?

Comment: http://www.rapidonline.com/Tools-Equipment/Stannol-No-Clean-Flux-Pens-520395

Comment: You can click edit just below your question to add the extra information to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F-SW-22 is weakly corrosive and contains inorganic salts.

F-SW-33 is non-corrosive and is rosin free w/o halides.

You'd use F-SW-22 if there was solder-ability issues, but you must clean the board after wards.

You'd use F-SW-33 for a normal (cleaner) situation, and is advertised as no-clean .  I'd recommend you clean it anyways.